# Does Oracle support the VALUES expression construct?

Tags: oracle

PostgreSQL supports the SQL spec's `VALUES` expression in what the spec calls a `<table value constructor>`

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
  (1, 'one'),
  (2, 'two'),
  (3, 'three')
) AS t(num,letter);
 num | letter
-----+--------
   1 | one
   2 | two
   3 | three
(3 rows)
```

Trying it on [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4624a03effd99cbe6e6404bf73107822), I can't get it to work in Oracle. I keep getting

> ORA-00903: invalid table name

Does Oracle support the `VALUES ( expression [, ...] )`? If not what is the alternative method of creating a virtual table from row-literals provided in the query?

Answer (score 9):

> *Does Oracle support the VALUES ( expression [, ...] )? If not what is the alternative method of creating a table from row-literals provided in the query?*

The most concise option we've got is with `insert all`:

> ```
> insert all 
>   into t values(1,'one')
>   into t values(2,'two')
>   into t values(3,'three')
> select * from dual
> ```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> NUM | WORD 
> --: | :----
>   1 | one  
>   2 | two  
>   3 | three
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=54fce965c7f478a8a85570f9f315324a)*

---

Note that the syntax is an extension to the standard and allows inserting into multiple tables with a single statement and conditional inserts, as the example shows:

> ```
> insert all
> when 1 = 1 then
>   into t values (num, word)
> when num > 0 then
>   into t values (-num, 'minus ' || word)
> select 0 as num, 'zero' as word from dual union all 
> select 1, 'one'   from dual union all
> select 2, 'two'   from dual union all 
> select 3, 'three' from dual ;
> ```
>
> ```
> 7 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> NUM | WORD       
> --: | :----------
>   0 | zero       
>   1 | one        
>   2 | two        
>   3 | three      
>  -1 | minus one  
>  -2 | minus two  
>  -3 | minus three
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e0cea686f2fa376f70b92718b34f687a)*

Answer (score 7):

Here is [Feature Request 13697: *Add support for the VALUES() constructor*](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13697), so it's not currently supported. In that ticket you can see the workaround,

> The above query can currently be emulated (quite tediously) in Oracle using:
>
> ```
> SELECT 1 FROM dual
> UNION ALL
> SELECT 2 FROM dual
> ```

So in Oracle, you'd use

```
SELECT 1 AS num, 'one' AS letter FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'two'   FROM dual
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'three' FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

No Love for CTES?

```
WITH CTE_VALUES
AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS NUM_VAL, 'one' AS TEXT_VAL FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS NUM_VAL, 'two' AS TEXT_VAL FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS NUM_VAL, 'three' AS TEXT_VAL FROM DUAL
)
--Then use the CTE as you desire in your query.  Nothing Permanent at all
SELECT NUM_VAL, 
TEXT_VAL 
FROM CTE_VALUES;
```

Comment: It's still the same mechanism to create the table that I found on the issue: `SELECT ... UNION ALL` (it's just in a CTE but that's not doing anything special)

Comment: Agreed @EvanCarroll and I definitely upvoted your answer, but the OP asked about creating a virtual table.  Either a temp table or CTE would be the approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 23c now support VALUES :
https://oracle-base.com/articles/23c/table-values-constructor-23c

```
select *
from   (values
          (4, 'FOUR', 'Description for FOUR'),
          (5, 'FIVE', 'Description for FIVE'),
          (6, 'SIX', 'Description for SIX')
       ) a (id, code, description);
```